# Trying to get CLI app STDOUT through a pipe but blocked till buffer is fulfilled

Tags: c, macos, unix, logging, pipe

I am working now on a **macOS Sierra**, **which does not have the /proc/sys/fs/pipe-max-size nor fcntl's F_SETPIPE_SZ**. (Darwin macos-1012 16.7.0 Darwin Kernel Version 16.7.0: Thu Jun 15 17:36:27 PDT 2017; root:xnu-3789.70.16~2/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64)

I am trying to get macOS' `log stream` output through `pipe()` since I am opening it with `execvp()` but I only get its logs when the whole buffer is filled (16384 bytes), this may take hours, days, or more depending on the filter used with `log stream`.

When I run `log stream` in a command-line it shows log by log and there is no need to wait for the 16384 bytes to be written on STDOUT. But I do have to wait also when I redirect STDOUT as follows:

```sh
# log stream --style syslog 1> output.log
```

And, watching the file with a "tail -f", still get logs only when chunks of 16384 bytes are completed.

This only happens on this macOS version, in higher ones this works fine and every log is flushed immediately, not having to wait for the buffer to be filled.

If someone knows how to solve this or if there is any workaround I will be very grateful.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Buffering is something that most OS do in order to maintain good performance.  Depending on how the log is created by the application(s) you're watching, there may be options to cause them to flush the buffers more frequently.  You haven't given any information about how they're created, though, so I'm at a loss to help you beyond saying there are often flush commands that can be used, and sometimes buffer sizes can be controlled.  TERM output is not buffered (unlike other options), and that's why output there seems immediate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use command like:

```
unbuffer log stream --style syslog 1> output.log
```

the command `unbuffer` is part of package `expect`

Comment: Hi @Romeo thanks for your answer, it worked that way :)

Comment: @MarianoKoremblum, if you are happy with my answer you may consider to mark it as accepted :)